# Is there a way to calculate standard deviation on a range of cells only for cells where the value is greater than 0 in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a range of cells, say A1 to A100. I want to calculate the standard deviation for that range of cells but only take into account cells where the value is greater than 0. Is there a way to do this in excel? I tried `=stdev(if(A1:A100>0,A1:A100,0))` but it does not seem to be giving me the right results.

Comment: remove the `,0` and make sure you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to [Scott's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125909/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-standard-deviation-on-a-range-of-cells-only-for-cell#comment108138679_61125909), I would use [`STDEV.P`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-P-function-6E917C05-31A0-496F-ADE7-4F4E7462F285):

`=STDEV.P(IF(A1:A100>0,A1:A100))` and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel supports `FILTER()`, try:

```
=STDEV(FILTER(A1:A100,A1:A100>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting all the zero values back to zero
=stdev(if(A1:A100>0,A1:A100**,0**))

Instead, use this:
=stdev(if(A1:A100>0,A1:A100))